# Split translation results with pandas in Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns, translation

I'm doing a traslation of words in csv/excel files using Google Colab and Pandas here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator 
# read from an excel file
df = pd.read_excel('/content/Libro2.xlsx')
translator = Translator()  
df = df.apply(translator.translate,src='en',dest='es').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
```

So basically my input from excel is this one:
[image]

My output is this with this line in specific `df = df.apply(translator.translate,src='en',dest='es').apply(getattr, args=('text',))` so the problem here is I'm getting the format for a csv file, I would like to keet it with the format of the input, so I would like to have my data frame to export in to csv as usual. Here is my output:
[image]

The output that I would like to have is like the first image just in case is not clear my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to apply the function *elementwise*, you can use Pandas [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split()])

translator = Translator()
df_tr = df.applymap(lambda w: translator.translate(w, src='en',dest='es').text)
print(df_tr)
```

Output *df_tr*

```py
    0       1       2      3      4          5   6     7      8
0  la  rápido  marrón  zorro  salta  terminado  la  vago  perro
```